# Gzip deflate noncompressed data format

Tags: gzip, compression, deflate

After reading [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951) and manually wrote a simple gzip file that contains non-compressed data. The uncompressed data file only has one character 'a' with no additional spaces or line breaks. The content of the gzip file is
`1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 80 00 7f ff 86 43 be b7 e8 01 00 00 00`.

When I was trying to unzip it under Linux system, it gave me an error "gzip: xxx.gz: unexpected end of file".

I think I followed the deflate format of non-compressed data block mentioned in 3.2.4. After 10 bytes gzip header,

1. `01`: **BFINAL=1** and **BTYPE=00**
2. `8000`: **LEN=1**
3. `7fff`: **NLEN**
4. `86`: **a**

Followed by CRC and Size.

Can anyone point out anything wrong or missing in the gzip file? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`8000` is length 128, not 1. `0100` would be length 1. (Interestingly, you managed to correctly represent the total uncompressed length at the end as `01 00 00 00`.)

Also an `a` is hex `61`, not `86`.

So the correct stream would be:

```
1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 01 00 fe ff 61 43 be b7 e8 01 00 00 00
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dr. Adler. I actually figured out just 5 mins ago. The reason I got 8000 for length 1 is I thought everything in deflate encoding would start with the least significant bit, just like in static Huffman encoding.